# @vue/cli build dist/ folder doesn't render when hosted as a sub-directory

Tags: vue.js, build, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I am making a simple 2 page website with `@vue/cli / vue version 3.5.5`.

So far so good, when i run the website locally with `npm run serve` and then create my dist/ folder with `npm run build` .

When I add the files from the dist/ folder to the root of my hosting and access the production environment on `http://www.my-website.com` the page renders and runs normally.

However I want to host the app in the sub-directory but this messes up the routes as the index.html doesn't render. 
When accessing `http://www.my-website.com/dist` : the index.html is returned blank and with error messages in the console:

```
app.a1183de6.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

chunk-vendors.ff22d1fb.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

about.ad763791.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

app.a1183de6.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

*Provide background including what you've already tried*

I've spent hours and hours searching and the most common thing is to create a `vue.config.js` file and to change the root path into a sub-directory instead

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/dist/'
    : '/'
}
```

I also tried this but it doesn't work:

```
// module.exports = {
// publicPath:' /dist/ '
// }
```

I put the `vue.config.js` file  at the root of the project folder as indicated but it seems to be ignored on `npm run build`

*Describe the expected and actual results:*

I would like to render my vue-app in a sub-directory such as :

`http://www.website.com/dist`

But right now, i get a blank index.html page and error messages in the console when i host my project in a sub-directory. the project runs fine if i host it in the root

Answer (score 2):

nvm... it's working now ....

Created in root of project: `vue.config.js`

Added the following:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/dist/'
}
```

After running `npm run build` the paths to the js and css files now include the sub-directory

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur even if you are not creating a specific folder under the distribution folder. In that case see the following solution:

By default, index.html is generated with the link tags like the following:

```
<link href=/js/chunk-vendors.2f2d9c51.js rel=preload as=script>
```

Adding an unneeded slash at the beginning so its trying to search for the js and css files in the wrong path.
You actually need it like the following:

```
<link href=js/chunk-vendors.2f2d9c51.js rel=preload as=script>
```

without the leading slash character.

The leading forward slash '/' means the path is absolute to the root directory and not the current directory.

In order to fix it just add a **vue.config.js** file to your vue project containing the following code:

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: ''
};
```

It will assure that the index.html will be generated as shown above.